# Vaadin: how to set drop criterion on TreeGrid

Tags: vaadin, treegrid, vaadin8

I'am trying to allow dropping items in a TreeGrid when a condition becomes true e.g. node is not a leaf.

Node:

```
public class Node {
    List<Node> children;
   ...
    public boolean isLeaf() {
      return children.isEmpty()
    }
}
```

TreeView:

```
public class TreeView extends TreeGrid<Node> {
    public TreeView(){
        ...
    TreeGridDropTarget<Node> dropTarget = new TreeGridDropTarget<>(this, DropMode.ON_TOP);
    dropTarget.setDropEffect(DropEffect.MOVE);
    dropTarget.addGridDropListener(event -> {
        event.getDragSourceExtension().ifPresent(source -> {
            Notification.show("it works");
            });
        });
     }
  }
```

How to check if grid element is allowed to contain subelement? So how to add acceptance criteria?

Comment: There is a `setDropCriteriaScript` method available in the drop target extension but this involves some hacking with JavaScript, so I wouldn't recommend to use it. Also, I don't if you have the right context there. Another option is to extend the `TreeGrid` and do some client side programming but this is not that easy.

Comment: Can you get Node object using `(Node) source.getSource()` ?

Comment: @avix I would like to have a check on the client side, so on hover should be there an for example an prohibited icon.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich do you habe any examples?

Comment: I did not do anything like this before, so unfortunately I have no example.